# Get values from one textbox and put them in another textboxes

Tags: c#, textbox, parseint

I have values from a textbox :

```
"r, 00.00m,0000521135Hz,0000000000c,0000000.000s, 025.1C"
```

and I want to make each value show in another textboxes like this:

```
textbox 1:
a: "00.00"
textbox 2:
b: "0000521135"
textbox 3:
c: "0000000.000"
textbox 4:
d: "025.1"
```

I can do this in arduino using `parseInt()`, 
I wonder how to do this in c#, any help?

Comment: If you had typed "parse int c#" into Google, you would've gotten an answer a lot faster, with a lot less typing -- and a lot fewer people telling you to google it, to boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a `string.split()` function to extract value from first textbox.

```
string baseStr = "r, 00.00m,0000521135Hz,0000000000c,0000000.000s, 025.1C";
List<string> colStr= test.Split(new char[','], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

and then remove alphabet using regular expression

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
...
Textbox1.Text = Regex.Replace(colStr[1], "[A-Za-z]", "");
Textbox2.Text = Regex.Replace(colStr[2], "[A-Za-z]", ""));
...
```

Comment: thank you very much, you guys really help me finish this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the idea how to put the data in the textboxes. I have done it for a string variable.

```
string s1 = "r, 00.00m,0000521135Hz,0000000000c,0000000.000s, 025.1C";
string[] spliteds1 = s1.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string txt1 = "";
foreach(string elem in spliteds1)
{
    if(Regex.Replace(elem, "[^0-9.]", "") != "")
    {
        txt1 = txt1 + Regex.Replace(elem, "[^0-9.]", "") + ",";
    }
}
```

This code will put the in txt1 with comma seperator. You can run your loop for textboxes.

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you very much, you guys really help me finish this problem.